# Unity game engine question

Tags: unity

I am trying to make a game that needs to include various math problems. I am using the Unity game engine to make my game. The engine doesn’t recognize various math symbols like fractions, superscript, Sigma, subscript, etc. can anyone help me understand how I can display those math symbols within my game using the Unity game engine?

Comment: Hello, this has nothing to do with softwre recommendations. Please check https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic